# Is there a way to configuring Solr to run on Amazon S3 with the index files on S3 and not local storage?

Tags: solr, amazon-s3

I would like to know if there is a way to configure Apache Solr to index files stored on S3 and also to keep the index files on S3 as well.  I would like to have a load balanced (LD) scheme where multiple processors can share the master index.  This would allow me to bring up additional EC2 instances with Solr and point them to a common repository and index.

I am using PHP and would greatly appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Solr has a distributed search feature which you can use to sync indexes in different locations. Use master-slave replication between your locations. A Solr index (physical files) are **not** meant to be written by several processes. Or use Solandra (**exotic software warning!**) to use Cassandra's high throughput and "database is available, even when an entire datacenter goes down".

Comment: All I want to do is run Solr on a an EC2 instance with the index files created and residing on S3.  I also want the source document directory be on S3 (a different bucket if possible).  I would only have a single Process writing to the master index file.  My question is how do I configure Solr to map to S3 for both master index files storage and document storage.  I have seen install docs only for locally attached storage.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485812/how-to-implement-lucenenet-using-amazon-s3/10490568#10490568) if you're still on this.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new project called [`lucene-s3directory`](https://github.com/albogdano/lucene-s3directory). It enables Lucene to **read and write** indices to/from AWS S3 directly and does not need a local filesystem. I'm pretty sure it can easily be adapted for Solr. It's pretty early stage so use with caution.

```java
S3Directory dir = new S3Directory("my-lucene-index");
dir.create();
// use it in your code in place of FSDirectory, for example
dir.close();
dir.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

As for indexing files stored in AWS S3 see [here](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/help/Create+a+New+S3+Data+Source). However, storing the Solr index in S3/EBS is something I did not try yet.. mounting a shared EBS volume might work.