# How To implement LuceneNet using Amazon S3

Tags: lucene, amazon-s3, lucene.net

I'm trying to implement Lucene in my app using Amazon S3 to storage the indexes that I generate, but I can find any code examples or a clear article. So anyone that have some kind of experience with this please give a guide or something that can help me start

Comment: This can be a good starting point: [Azure Library for Lucene.Net (Full Text Indexing for Azure)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538)

Answer (score 3):

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186137/is-there-a-way-to-configuring-solr-to-run-on-amazon-s3-with-the-index-files-on-s).
[Here](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/02/01/solr-shines-through-the-cloud-lucidworks-solr-on-ec2/)'s an interesting article of how the biggest Solr service provider Lucid Imagination proposes to deploy their Solr implementation on EC2.
And [here](http://www.lucidimagination.com/about/news/releases/lucid-imagination-search-service-powers-flexible-cost-effective-enterprise-wide)'s their Search-as-a-Service solution.

If you're not bound to S3, you can use dedicated Solr cloud service called [WebSolr](http://websolr.com/).

Also, if you need complete ALM/CI solution for your development project, there's a WebSolr module included in [CloudBees](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Websolr).